# How do I use batch apex for this?

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to figure out how to use batch apex for an apex class like the one below.
The first query itself returns over 50K records and thats throwing an error.

I am also using a Map for that query whereas batch apex uses a list. I am in a horrible pinch right now and I need to push this to production. Any help would be appreciated.

```
global class Non_OLMP_Last_Course_Check implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {            
        Map<ID,hed__Program_Enrollment__c> program_Enrollments = new Map<ID,hed__Program_Enrollment__c>([Select Id, Name, hed__Enrollment_Status__c,hed__Program_Plan__r.hed__Version__c,Program_Version__c, hed__Contact__r.Id, hed__Program_Plan__r.Name, hed__GPA__c, Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c From hed__Program_Enrollment__c Where hed__Program_Plan__r.Name IN ('Air Command and Staff College','Squadron Officer School','Air War College','Air Command and Staff College Supplemental') AND hed__Enrollment_Status__c = 'Active' ]);
        Set<ID> program_Enrollment_ID_Set = new Set<ID>();
        
        Map<hed__Program_Enrollment__c, List<hed__Course_Enrollment__c>> map_Of_PE_To_CC_List = new Map<hed__Program_Enrollment__c, List<hed__Course_Enrollment__c>>();
        for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c pe: program_Enrollments.values()){
            program_Enrollment_ID_Set.add(pe.Id); 
        }
        
        
        List<hed__Course_Enrollment__c> courseConnections = [SELECT Name, hed__Program_Enrollment__r.hed__Program_Plan__r.Name,hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Name, Course_ID__c,
                                                             Id, Cloud_Course__c, hed__Status__c, hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c, hed__Program_Enrollment__r.hed__Enrollment_Status__c, Current_Seminar__c, hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.hed__Course_ID__c, hed__Credits_Attempted__c, Common_Course__c , hed__Credits_Earned__c, hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id, hed__Contact__r.Id FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c WHERE hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id IN :program_Enrollment_ID_Set AND Course_ID__c != 'GSS-502A' AND (hed__Status__c = 'Former' OR hed__Status__c = 'Current')  ];
        
        if(courseConnections.size() != 0){
            for(hed__Course_Enrollment__c cc: courseConnections) {
                if(program_Enrollments.containsKey(cc.hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id)) {
                    if(!map_Of_PE_To_CC_List.containsKey(program_Enrollments.get(cc.hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id))) {
                        map_Of_PE_To_CC_List.put(program_Enrollments.get(cc.hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id), new List<hed__Course_Enrollment__c>());
                    } 
                    map_Of_PE_To_CC_List.get(program_Enrollments.get(cc.hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id)).add(cc);
                }
            }
            
            
            List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate = new List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c>();
            System.debug('**********************************************');

            for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c pe : map_Of_PE_To_CC_List.keySet()) {
                Double foundationalUnits = 0.0;
                Double focusedUnits = 0.0;
                Integer facilitatedCourses = 0;
                for(hed__Course_Enrollment__c cc: map_Of_PE_To_CC_List.get(pe)){
                    if(cc.Cloud_Course__c == false){
                        if(cc.hed__Status__c == 'Former' && cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c == cc.hed__Credits_Earned__c){
                            if(cc.hed__Credits_Earned__c != null){
                                foundationalUnits = foundationalUnits + cc.hed__Credits_Earned__c;
                                system.debug('Former foundational Course name: '+ cc.Name);

                            }
                            
                        } 
                        
                        else if(cc.hed__Status__c == 'Current'){
                            if(cc.hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c == 'Self-paced' && cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c != null ){
                                foundationalUnits = foundationalUnits + cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c;
                                system.debug('Current foundational self-paced Course name: '+ cc.Name);

                            }
                            
                            else if(cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c != null  && cc.Current_Seminar__c == true){
                                foundationalUnits = foundationalUnits + cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c;
                                system.debug('Current foundational Course name: '+ cc.Name);
                                
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else if(cc.Cloud_Course__c == true){
                        if(cc.hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c == 'facilitated'){
                            facilitatedCourses = facilitatedCourses + 1;
                            system.debug('Focused Facilitated Course name: '+ cc.Name);
                        }
                        
                        if(cc.hed__Status__c == 'Former' && cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c == cc.hed__Credits_Earned__c){
                            if(cc.hed__Credits_Earned__c != null){
                                focusedUnits = focusedUnits + cc.hed__Credits_Earned__c;
                                system.debug('Former focused Course name: '+ cc.Name);
                            }
                        } 
                        else if(cc.hed__Status__c == 'Current'){
                            if(cc.hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c == 'Self-paced' && cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c != null ){
                                focusedUnits = focusedUnits + cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c;
                                system.debug('Current focused Self-paced Course name: '+ cc.Name);

                            }
                            
                            else if(cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c != null  && cc.Current_Seminar__c == true){
                                focusedUnits = focusedUnits + cc.hed__Credits_Attempted__c;
                                system.debug('Current focused Course name: '+ cc.Name);
                                
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
                System.debug('PROGRAM ENROLLMENT: '+ pe.Name);
                System.debug('PROGRAM Plan: '+ pe.hed__Program_Plan__r.Name);
                
                System.debug('FoundationalUnits: '+ foundationalUnits);
                System.debug('FocusedUnits: '+ focusedUnits);
                System.debug('Facilitated: '+ facilitatedCourses);
                
                System.debug('**********************************************');

                
                
                if(pe.hed__Program_Plan__r.Name == 'Air Command and Staff College' && foundationalUnits == 43.0  && focusedUnits >= 9.0 && facilitatedCourses == 1 ){
                    pe.Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c = true;
                    listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate.add(pe);
                }
                else if(pe.hed__Program_Plan__r.Name == 'Air War College'  ) {
                    if(pe.Program_Version__c == '18' && foundationalUnits == 30.0  && focusedUnits >= 9.0 && facilitatedCourses == 1){
                        pe.Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c = true;
                        listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate.add(pe);
                        
                        
                    } else if(pe.Program_Version__c == '19' && foundationalUnits == 31.0  && focusedUnits >= 9.0 && facilitatedCourses == 1){
                        pe.Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c = true;
                        listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate.add(pe);
                    }
                }  
                else if(pe.hed__Program_Plan__r.Name == 'Air Command and Staff College Supplemental' && foundationalUnits == 31) {
                    pe.Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c = true;
                    listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate.add(pe);
                }  
                
                else if(pe.hed__Program_Plan__r.Name == 'Squadron Officer School' && foundationalUnits == 27.0  && focusedUnits >= 9.0 && facilitatedCourses == 1 ) {
                    pe.Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c = true;
                    listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate.add(pe);
                }       
            }
            if(listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate.size() != 0){
               // System.debug('ListOfPE to Update: '+ listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate );
               // Update listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate;
                Non_OLMP_Last_Course_Batch myBatchObject = new Non_OLMP_Last_Course_Batch(listOfProgramEnrollmentsToUpdate); 
                Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject, 1000);
                
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion is easy, just change the first few lines of your class:

```
global class Non_OLMP_Last_Course_Check implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {            
        Map<ID,hed__Program_Enrollment__c> program_Enrollments = new Map<ID,hed__Program_Enrollment__c>([Select Id, Name, hed__Enrollment_Status__c,hed__Program_Plan__r.hed__Version__c,Program_Version__c, hed__Contact__r.Id, hed__Program_Plan__r.Name, hed__GPA__c, Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c From hed__Program_Enrollment__c Where hed__Program_Plan__r.Name IN ('Air Command and Staff College','Squadron Officer School','Air War College','Air Command and Staff College Supplemental') AND hed__Enrollment_Status__c = 'Active' ]);
        Set<ID> program_Enrollment_ID_Set = new Set<ID>();
```

To:

```
global class Non_OLMP_Last_Course_Check implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            [Select Id, Name, hed__Enrollment_Status__c,hed__Program_Plan__r.hed__Version__c,Program_Version__c, hed__Contact__r.Id, hed__Program_Plan__r.Name, hed__GPA__c, Non_OLMP_Final_Course__c From hed__Program_Enrollment__c Where hed__Program_Plan__r.Name IN ('Air Command and Staff College','Squadron Officer School','Air War College','Air Command and Staff College Supplemental') AND hed__Enrollment_Status__c = 'Active' ]
        );
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {

    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, hed__Program_Enrollment__c[] scope) {            
        Map<ID,hed__Program_Enrollment__c> program_Enrollments = new Map<ID,hed__Program_Enrollment__c>(scope);
        Set<ID> program_Enrollment_ID_Set = new Set<ID>();
```

Edit: I should say that the last part, where you call a separate batch, won't work in a Batchable execute method. Just do the DML directly, you should have plenty of DML rows for your operation and CPU time to burn. This answer was primarily directed at a "how do I convert a Schedulable to a Batchable" perspective.

Comment: Thanks for coming to my rescue again mate. How could I go about writing test cases for such a class ? Is there any resources you can direct me to ?